# Calculating Least Common Multiple (how do I know when there isn't one?)

Tags: java

The code below was my first attempt at a LCM (lowest common multiple) calculator with a user interface (UI code not shown) written months ago.  I know there are simpler ways to write this, but I'd like help understanding why sometimes THIS specific code is not finding a common multiple (with most number sets it works fine).

When a user inputs almost any number set, the app spits out the correct LCM.  But when the number set `1,234 / 2,345 / 5,432 / 4,321` is used, the app initially was stopping when `x` hit 536,870,912.  This was because the result of `x * mult` was a number that couldn't be held by the `int` primitive.  After changing `x` to a `double` and casting `result = (int) (mult * x)`, the code continues to function as expected but seems to increment `x` indefinitely.

```
public static void compare(){
    result = 0;
    int mult = 0;
    double x = 1;
    int[] nums = UserInterface.getNums();

    // finds highest number in user-input set
    for(int i  = 0; i < nums.length; i ++){
        if (nums[i] > mult) mult = nums[i];
    }

    // finds lowest common multiple
    for(int i  = 0; i < nums.length;){
        if((mult * x) % nums[i] == 0){      
            result = (int) (mult * x);              
            i++;
        }
        else{
            result = 0;
            x++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: a set of numbers always has a common multiple (the product of the entire set), so there is always a least common multiple. Because lcm(a,b) is necessarily larger or equal to max(a,b), you look like you're running into some very large numbers. If you want to keep the intermediate arithmetic under a,b, realize lcm(a,b) = (ab)/gcd(a,b).

Comment: Longest SO question I have ever seen. Far too long.

Comment: @MartinMeeser yeah I didn't actually read it...

Comment: That's indeed a lot of code for a simple algorithm. `gcd=function(x,y){return y===0?x:gcd(y,x%y)};lcm=function(x,y){return x*y/gcd(x,y)}`

Comment: also http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lcm%281234%2C+2345%2C+5432%2C+4321%29

Comment: Thanks guys.  I appreciate the explanations. Can u please reverse the downvotes? I come here to get help and learn, not be chastised.  The more you downvote genuine questions, yes the less likely people will come looking for help. I understand this is meant to stave off people who don't ask good questions, but you're hardly being fair.  I spent a lot of time trying to get this done and even more time preparing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the LCM of your test set must be less than or equal to 67,920,681,416,560.

In java the `int` datatype has a max value of 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647 so you are obviously going to get an overflow. You can change your code to use `long` throughout this has a max value of 2^64-1=18,446,744,073,709,551,615 so it should be sufficient for your calculation. If you need bigger values then look at the BigInteger class.

In javascript things are more complicated. All numbers are floating point so you loose accuracy. This probably mean the condition

```
    if((mult * x) % nums[i] == 0)
```

is never satisfied so your loop never quits.

Your algorithm is very basic, there are much better algorithms out there, elclanrs has one above and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple for some hints.

Also you should change the title of the question. As it stands it make no sense as any set of numbers must have a LCM.

Comment: Thanks Salix.  You're the only one that actually read my question.  Can you please upvote it because its pushing my rep down when people don't bother reading.  I'll edit it to make it more concise.